# Is there something like UIAccessibilityCustomAction for iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiaccessibility

I have an `UITableView` with a **swipe left** action on each row, which shows a **remove row** button. For **iOS > 7**,

I implemented an accessibility solution using `UIAccessibilityCustomAction`, so the `VoiceOver` can read this remove option when swipe the finger down on the screen, but unfortunately this class isn't supported on `iOS7`.

I know that must be some class similar, because on native Mail app, this behavior is implemented. But I don't know which class it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that this is not possible on iOS 7. It's pretty common to find behaviors in system apps that are not (yet) exposed via the public SDK. If this is a common action, you *could* choose to expose it some other way on iOS 7, perhaps by adding an accessibility element to the hierarchy.

Comment: What a pity! :/ But, thanks for the answer, Justin! I will try some work around to get this job done.

Comment: @PavlosNicolaou The question asks about iOS 7, specifically, where `UIAccessibilityCustomAction` is not available.